# Random number generated per .pdf form

Tags: javascript, foxit

I'm creating a .pdf form in Foxit which needs to be able to generate a random, unique number each time the form is used.
I presume the use of a button with javascript embedded is my best option however have not been successful in creating this.
Suggestions?

Comment: `var randomNumberField = this.getField("foo");`
Do you have a "foo" field to run this on and to later populate with a number?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`var randomNumberField = this.getField("foo");`

Do you have a "foo" field to run this on and to later populate with a number?

if you do, it's as simple as:

```
 var randomNumberField = this.getField("foo")
 if (randomNumberField .value.length == 0) {
 randomNumberField .value = util.printf("%06d", Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1));
 }
```

and setting the field to be ReadOnly. code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924206/save-a-random-number-in-a-pdf-file-using-javascript-in-adobe-acrobat)

no need for a button or anything, it runs on document load (i think?).

example pdf file (that will expire in 30 days....):
https://easyupload.io/ew86ge